# can't connect to client over VPN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn

I have VPN server PPPd on Ubuntu Server.

Next, I have PC-1 with Ubuntu. PC-1 connects to VPN server via VPN client. VPN Server's IP in VPN is `192.168.20.1`. PC-1 VPN IP is `192.168.20.111`.

Next I have PC-2 also connected to the VPN server. PC-2 IP in VPN is `192.168.20.101`. I can run SSH on PC-2 and connect to `192.168.20.1` Also I can run SSH session in that SSH to connect to PC-1. But I can't connect from PC-2 to PC-1.

If I try to SSH directly to `192.168.20.111` on PC-2 I get:

> Could not connect to `192.168.20.111` (port 22): Connection failed.

Also I can't ping `192.168.20.111` from PC-2. But I can ping VPN server on `192.168.20.1`. How can I connect to PC-2 to PC-1 over VPN?

Comment: Are you using a VPN technology such as OpenVPN?

Comment: In Webmin it shows as pptpd PPTP VPN Server